# Making All Column Name Lower Case MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have inherited a large MySQL database.

Its a mess: half the column names are upper case,  other mixed case,  other lower case.

I wish to standardize them

Is there a query I can run to alter each one so that they are all lower case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for rename all tables and columns to lower case:-

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' CHANGE `', COLUMN_NAME, '` `',
LOWER(COLUMN_NAME), '` ', COLUMN_TYPE, ';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{your schema name}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will be able to compose a query that will
1. Enumerate the tables in the database.
2. Enumerate the columns for each database.
3. If the column name is not equal to LCASE of its name, rename it to LCASE of its name.

When you post an example of what you've tried, I may be able to update this answer to be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

By [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' CHANGE ', column_name, ' ', 
   LOWER(column_name), ' ', column_type, ' ', extra,
CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN  ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END, ';')   AS line
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = '<DBNAME>' 
AND data_type IN ('char', 'varchar','INT', 'TINYINT',  'datetime','text','double','decimal')
ORDER BY line;
```

its not quite perfect but close enough.